# Express-validation returning wrong response error code

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-validator

I'm using Express-validation to validate request fields. everything is working as it supposed to be, except for the **response error code**.

I have the following code:

```js
//
// ValidationLeaner.js
const Joi = require('joi');

module.exports = {
  body: {
    name: Joi.string().min(3).max(20).required(),
    classifierId: Joi.number().integer().positive().required()
  }
}

//Route.js
const { Router } = require('express')
const Validate = require('express-validation')
const ValidationLearner = require('./ValidationLeaner')

const router = Router()

router.route('/').post(Validate(ValidationLearner), ...someFunction)

module.exports = router
```

When sending a `POST` request with body: `{name: "Leaner01", classifierId: false}`.
I receive the following response, which is correct:

```
{
  "status": 400,
  "statusText": "Bad Request",
  "errors": [
     {
       "field": [ "classifierId" ],
       "location": "body",
       "messages": [ "\"classifierId\" must be a number" ],
       "types": [ "number.base" ]
      }
  ]
}
```

Unfortunately the response code is  **500 Internal Server Error** and not **400** as pointed in the response body.

How can we make Express-validation send the same response code stated in the body (status: 400)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have an error handle in your main file (index, app or server.js) , because in the [express-validation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validation) docs it is required.

Can you add this error handler (or edit it if you already have) to your main file (index, app or server.js) and try again?

```js
const Validate = require("express-validation");

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // specific for validation errors
  if (err instanceof Validate.ValidationError)
    return res.status(err.status).json(err);

  // other type of errors, it *might* also be a Runtime Error
  return res.status(500).send(err.stack);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that changing this line

> const { ValidationLearner } = require('./ValidationLeaner')

into

> const ValidationLearner = require('./ValidationLeaner')

will change the result. Because in the first case ValidationLearner is undefined since ValidationLearner.js (is it ValidationLeaner.js or ValidationLearner.js) exports an object that has a first-level property named body and not ValidationLearner.

Comment: Sorry man, I removed some lines from the code before posting the question, I forgot to change this one. Just made the correction you mentioned, good observation. But the problem still persists.